# Cannot execute binary file on Ubuntu ./webupdater

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wxwidgets

1. I have downloaded "precompiled sample for GTK2" from here http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/webupdate/ on Ubuntu machine.
2. I extracted this, and it creates a folders "simple/v1.0.0" which contains executable file "webupdater".
3. When I run this command on terminal s5@s5-desktop:~/ble/simple/v1.0.0$ ./webupdater
   -bash: ./webupdater: cannot execute binary file
   it says can not execute binary file.

configuration of Ubuntu machine is given below.

s5@s5-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux s5-desktop 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Please help, Why this problem is coming.
Thanks and Regards
Brajesh...

Comment: Does this "webupdater" file have execute permission? You can check this with `ls -l webupdater`.

Comment: Also, what type of file is `webupdater`? What is the output of `file webupdater`? If it's a 64-bit binary, it won't run on a 32-bit system. Or maybe it's a script for which the interpreter is not installed (i.e. `python` or `perl` or `ruby` or ....?).

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu ? - check tha with the command :

```
uname -m
```

EG: "x86_64" is 64 bit, and "i686" is 32 bit.

Run the file command to see what the executable is :

```
file /bin/ls
```

These threads discuss this -

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1919786

https://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu

I am in Ubuntu 14.10, which no longer has ia32-libs, which used to fix this.
I have yet to find a solution to running a binary that is not installed.
In my case I am going to have to look at compiling the app on my system, and I will try and feed back to the original developer...

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons:

1. Check the file permissions, do  `chmod 777 webupdater` and then try executing again,
2. Check the type of file by executing `file webupdater` and compare it with your system `uname -r` , ie wether both are 32-bit, 64-bit or not. the `file webupdater` output can give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

When I executed file webupdater, it gives output given below

s5@s5-desktop:~/ble/simple/v1.0.0$ file webupdater
webupdater: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, stripped

and Ubuntu system is 32bit

thanks,
Brajesh...